Norm of projection operators on different function spaces
Let $\mathcal X$ be a measurable set endowed with a measure $\rho$ such that $\rho(\mathcal X)=1$. Let $\{\phi_i\}_i$ be an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathcal X,\rho)$.
What is the linear operator $L_d$ minimizing
$$\Lambda_d:=\sup_{\|f\|_\infty\le 1}\|L_d[f]\|_\infty$$
such that for every $\forall v\in \text{span}(\phi_1(\cdot),\dots \phi_d(\cdot))$ we have $L_d(v)=v$ (NOTE: also just the order in $d$, or even some reading advices are well appreciated).
My thoughts
Note that, if we were interested in minimizing the norm $L^2\to L^2$, a simple solution would have been given by the usual projection operator:
$$P_d[f](y):=\int_\mathcal X \sum_{i=1}^{d}\phi_i(y)\phi_i(x)f(x)\ dx.$$
In fact, being $\{\phi_i\}_i$ an orthonormal basis, any linear operator $L_d(\cdot)$ satisfiying the requirement can be written as
$$L_d[f](y)=\int_\mathcal X \sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{ij}\phi_i(y)\phi_i(x)f(x)\ dx \qquad \lambda_{ij}=\delta_{ij}\ \text{if}\ i\le d.$$
